# Tag for alcoholism

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, we have tag [alcoholic-alcoholism](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcoholic-alcoholism). I propose that the tag be renamed [alcoholism](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcoholism).

Since "alcoholic" is an adjective, I do not see the point of creating the synonym [alcoholic](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcoholic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented as suggested in question.